# Submit button does not submit form when disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The idea is to use a button which changes the text and disables itself on submit:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".autobutton").click(function(event) {
    // Show a spinner
    var nv = $(this).html();
    var nv2 = '<span class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></span> ' + nv;
    $(this).html(nv2);

    var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
    form.submit();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.php">
  <button class="autobutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If the button is a button type submit, this does not submit the form unless I remove the disabled property set. If the button is a type="button", nothing happens.

Comment: Where should be the form submitted? To which location say http in this case? You are missing action attribute

Comment: The actual form does have an action etc. I didn't provide a complete form here for simplicity.

Comment: the button type must be set to `submit` ... you must do something like `<button type='submit'>click me</button>`

Comment: @Ahmad buttons' type is submit by default.

Comment: Are you using any pseudo selector for the class autobutton

Comment: @Ahmad he is calling the form's `submit` function.  The type of the input is irrelevant.

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior.  Form submission occurs whether `disabled` is set or not

Answer (score 0):

It is a better idea to listen submit event on the form `$('form').submit(function(){...})`
instead of click on the button because a form can be submit with 'enter' in the last input without click on a button.
I don't know now but before button type submit was buggy and it was simpler to use input type="submit" with this method. after just change the css to have your input looking what you want.
if you return false in the submit listener it will block it.

And because you are already in the submit listener disable the button won't block the submit.

Else just use FormData and ajax.